# One User Multiple Place Login

Tags: reactjs, node.js

I want to adjust the following code so users are allowed to login on multiple browsers/devices. Currently the code below will logout users from other devices when logging in on a "new" device.

How can I adjust the code so I can allow users to be logged in at multiple places and they don't get logged out from other devices?

```js
async function loginNewUser(req, res) {
  const User = require("../models/user");
  const LoginInfo = require('../models/login_info');
  try {
    const { email, mobile, password, otp } = req.body;
    const params = [];
    if(email) {
      params.push({email: email});
    }
    if(mobile) {
      params.push({mobile_number: mobile});
    }
    if (password) {
      if (params.length === 0) {
        // If both email and mobile are absent, return an error
        return res.json({
          status:400,
          message:"Email or mobile is required"
        });
      }
      //const user_data = await User.findOne({ email: email });
      const user_data = await User.findOne({$or:params})
      if (user_data) {
        /**
         * need to write logic
         */
        const isfound = await compareHash(
          user_data.hashedPassword ? user_data.hashedPassword : "",
          password
        );
        if (isfound) {
          const ipaddr = req.header("x-forwarded-for") || req.connection.remoteAddress;
            const sys_info = req.headers["sec-ch-ua-platform"];
            const dat = req.headers["sec-ch-ua"];
            const reg = /"[a-zA-Z "]*/mg;
            const sr = dat?dat.match(reg).toString():"NA";
            const browser_info = sr.split('",').join();
            const origin = req.get('origin');
            
            const jwtkey=user_data.user_id.split("/")[0]
            const payload = {
              sub: user_data.user_id,
              iat: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000),
            };
            let token=jwt.sign(payload,jwtkey,{
              expiresIn:"24h"
            }
            )
            let access_token = createAccessToken({ br: browser_info, os: sys_info?sys_info:"NA", ip: ipaddr, ui: user_data.user_id, og: origin?origin:"chintu" });

            let time = new Date().getTime();
            await LoginInfo.create({
                user_id: user_data.user_id,
                sys_info: sys_info ? sys_info.split('"').join("") : "NA",
                browser_info: browser_info ? browser_info.split('"').join(" ") : "NA",
                ip_address: ipaddr,
                timestamp: time,
                access_token: access_token,
                auth_token:token
            });
            await User.updateOne({_id:user_data._id}, {
              $set:{
                auth_token:token
              }
            })

          if(user_data.authenticator == 2) {
            if(!otp) {
              return res.status(400).json({
                message: "Your Google Authenticator On Please Enter The OTP",
              });
            }
            const speakeasy = require("speakeasy-latest");
            const { base32: secret } = user_data.secret_key;
            var tokenValidates = speakeasy.totp.verify({
              secret: secret,
              encoding: "base32",
              token: otp,
              window: 6,
            });
            if (tokenValidates) {
              
              return res.json({
                status: 200,
                error: false,
                params: {
                    role: user_data.user_role ? user_data.user_role : 0,
                    ev: user_data.is_email_verified ? user_data.is_email_verified : false,
                    ask_login_otp: user_data.ask_login_otp,
                    mobile_no: user_data.mobile_number ? user_data.mobile_number : 0,
                    user_id: user_data.user_id ? user_data.user_id : undefined,
                    token:token
                },
                message: "Login successfully!",
              });
            } else {
              return res.status(400).json({
                message: "Invalid OTP",
              });
            }
          } else if(user_data.authenticator == 1) {
              const { verifyOTP } = require("../utils/validator");
              const OtpBuffer = require("../models/otp_buffer");
              const OTP_LENGTH = 6;
              try {
                if (email && otp && otp.toString().length == OTP_LENGTH) {
                  const otp_object = await OtpBuffer.findOne({ email: email });
                  if (verifyOTP(otp_object.mobile_otp, otp)) {
                    await OtpBuffer.updateOne(
                      { email: email },
                      {
                        $set: {
                          mobile_otp: null,
                        },
                      }
                    );
            
                      return res.json({
                        status: 200,
                        error: false,
                        params: {
                            role: user_data.user_role ? user_data.user_role : 0,
                            ev: user_data.is_email_verified ? user_data.is_email_verified : false,
                            ask_login_otp: user_data.ask_login_otp,
                            mobile_no: user_data.mobile_number ? user_data.mobile_number : 0,
                            user_id: user_data.user_id ? user_data.user_id : undefined,
                            token:token
                        },
                        message: "Login successfully!",
                      });
                  } else {
                    return res.status(400).json({
                      message: "Invalid OTP",
                    });
                  }
                } else {
                  return res.status(400).json({
                    message: "Your Mobile Authenticator On Please Enter The OTP",
                  });
                }
              } catch (error) {
                console.log(
                  "Error: from: src>controller>auth.js>loginNewUser: ",
                  error.message
                );
                return res.status(400).json({
                  message: "Something went wrong, please try again!",
                });
              }
          } else {
            
            return res.json({
              status: 200,
              error: false,
              params: {
                  role: user_data.user_role ? user_data.user_role : 0,
                  ev: user_data.is_email_verified ? user_data.is_email_verified : false,
                  ask_login_otp: user_data.ask_login_otp,
                  mobile_no: user_data.mobile_number ? user_data.mobile_number : 0,
                  user_id: user_data.user_id ? user_data.user_id : undefined,
                  token:token
              },
              message: "Login successfully!",
            });
          }
        } else {
          return res
            .status(400)
            .json({ message: "Username or password not found" });
        }
      } else {
        return res
          .status(400)
          .json({ message: "Username or password not found" });
      }
    } else {
      return res
        .status(400)
        .json({ message: "Username or password not found" });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(
      "Error: from: controller>auth.js>loginUser: ",
      error.message,
      error
    );
    return res
      .status(400)
      .json({ message: "Something went wrong, please try again" });
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh currently the user is only able to login on a single browser at one time? You want to support multiple logins for the user, right?

Comment: Yes You Are Right

Comment: @ShivanshuSingh I've rephrased your question based on your input. Can you please reflect and edit the text when not satisfied?

Comment: Yes I Tell You My Question Is That In this code i provide user can login only one browser when login 2nd browser then logout 1st browser but my expecation is user can login multiple device/browser not log out anywhrere